# Excel VBA Web Browser Run-time error '424' object required

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with an Excel workbook that includes Google Maps in it. So far, everything worked correctly, but it suddenly started throwing a run-time error.

The map is simply an ActiveX Microsoft Web Browser which is activated by a Button and reads a part of the map URL from a cell that is specified in a cell next to the Button.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim rowNum As Long
  rowNum = Sheets("Map").Range("B2")
  rowNum = rowNum - 43396
  MapViewer1.Navigate ("https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=" + 
Sheets("Map").Range("D" & rowNum).Value)

End Sub
```

So, as I said, this code worked for a long time, but it stopped and now reveals an error at the line "MapViewer1.Navigate...". Nobody else has modified the workbook's VBA. What can be the reason of that?

Comment: Is `MapViewer1` still available?  Is the navigate line all one line or is the Sheets bit on a separate line?

Comment: The "MapViewer1" is available and `MapViewer1.Navigate ("https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=" + 
Sheets("Map").Range("D" & rowNum).Value)` is all one line

Comment: Is the button on the same sheet as the webbrowser?

Comment: Yes. [filling15chars]

Comment: @화이트케이크 Can you tell whats the value in cell `Sheets("Map").Range("D1").Value`? Just trying to access the link in browser

Comment: No, sorry, I can't - due to the restrictions of data privacy. What I can tell you is that if you have a custom Google map with URL `https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`, the value was the `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong for myself.

It turned out that actually nothing was wrong with the workbook.
The computer which I worked on having the WebBrowser issue, had a registry key set to a value that disables some of the ActiveX controls.

---

The solution for anyone who would have the same problem with ActiveX can be found here: [LINK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2793374/cannot-insert-certain-scriptable-activex-controls-into-office-2013-doc).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just somewhere to show code.

I've tried the following, which allows me to debug each of the "wrappers" around the web browser, with the final object `w` being the browser.  Take a look at `Navigate2` also.  Check this code, make sure `s` and `o` and `w` are all populated.

```
Sub t()

Dim s As Shape
Dim o As OLEObject
Dim w As WebBrowser

Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("mapviewer")
Set o = s.OLEFormat.Object
Set w = o.Object

w.Navigate "www.google.co.uk"
w.Navigate2 ""  '   <-- try this also

End Sub
```

Comment: The question is closed, but thank you for the willingness to help!